# Cloudflare Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a URL using Scrapy with Cloudflare but I can't obtain any results:

```
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem 
cache storage in C:\Users\Luis\Mister\.scrapy\httpcache
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console 
listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://www.mister-auto.es/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://www.mister-auto.es/global_search2.html? idx=prod_monoindex_ESes&q=FEBI+BILSTEIN> (referer: None) ['cached']
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 633,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 20858,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 9, 20, 14, 0, 833000),
 'httpcache/hit': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 9, 20, 14, 0, 594000)}
2018-07-09 22:14:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As the website is protected by Cloudflare, I've installed this:
    https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-cloudflare-middleware

When I modified my `settings.py`, I obtained the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", 
line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
98, in crawl six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
80, in crawl self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
105,in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", 
line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
   self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 
58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 
34, in from_settings mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 
44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in 
import_module__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named scraping_hub.middlewares
```

At this point I'm stuck. I don't know if I have to change the `settings.py` or `middlewares.py`.

Could you help me please? I'd like to improve my skills. ;)

P.S. I've added my `middlewares.py`:

```
from scrapy import signals


class MercadoSpiderMiddleware(object):
# Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
# scrapy acts as if the spider middleware does not modify the
# passed objects.

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # This method is used by Scrapy to create your spiders.
    s = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
    return s

def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
    # Called for each response that goes through the spider
    # middleware and into the spider.

    # Should return None or raise an exception.
    return None

def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    # Called with the results returned from the Spider, after
    # it has processed the response.

    # Must return an iterable of Request, dict or Item objects.
    for i in result:
        yield i

def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
    # Called when a spider or process_spider_input() method
    # (from other spider middleware) raises an exception.

    # Should return either None or an iterable of Response, dict
    # or Item objects.
    pass

def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
    # Called with the start requests of the spider, and works
    # similarly to the process_spider_output() method, except
    # that it doesn’t have a response associated.

    # Must return only requests (not items).
    for r in start_requests:
        yield r

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)


class MercadoDownloaderMiddleware(object):
# Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
# scrapy acts as if the downloader middleware does not modify the
# passed objects.

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # This method is used by Scrapy to create your spiders.
    s = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
    return s

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    # Called for each request that goes through the downloader
    # middleware.

    # Must either:
    # - return None: continue processing this request
    # - or return a Response object
    # - or return a Request object
    # - or raise IgnoreRequest: process_exception() methods of
    #   installed downloader middleware will be called
    return None

def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    # Called with the response returned from the downloader.

    # Must either;
    # - return a Response object
    # - return a Request object
    # - or raise IgnoreRequest
    return response

def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
    # Called when a download handler or a process_request()
    # (from other downloader middleware) raises an exception.

    # Must either:
    # - return None: continue processing this exception
    # - return a Response object: stops process_exception() chain
    # - return a Request object: stops process_exception() chain
    pass

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

Comment: I think that I´ve a problem at the Download.middleware but I don´t know how to set up it correctly.

Comment: the middleware was not installed correctly as it says scrapy cannot find it. How did you install it?

Comment: Hi thank you for your help!                                                                            
Installed from here: _pip install scrapy_cloudflare_middleware_. A the "settings.py": **DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scraping_hub.middlewares.CloudFlareMiddleware': 560}**. At the "middlewares.py": **class MercadoDownloaderMiddleware(object)**:
    # Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
    # scrapy acts as if the downloader middleware does not modify the
    # passed objects.

Comment: I've added my "middlewares.py" to my question.

Comment: Hello again! Could be the that the project “pip install scrapy_cloudflare_middleware.” doesn’t be active?

Comment: is your scrapy and the middleware on the same python? make a virtualenv: `python3 -m venv ~/virtualenvs/scrapy && source ~/virtualenvs/scrapy/activate && pip install scrapy scrapy_cloudflare_middleware`

Comment: Hi! I´m not able to pass this: _2018-07-25 22:35:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: **Crawled (200) <GET https://www.m
ister-auto.es/robots.txt> (referer: None)**
2018-07-25 22:35:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.m
ister-auto.es/global_search2.html?idx=prod_monoindex_ESes&q=FEBI+BILSTEIN> (refe
rer: None)
2018-07-25 22:35:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)_. I´ve changed my middleware but I´m not able to obtain information, **do you know why I obtain the conde 200 refer none?**

Comment: You should open a new question for this issue. Is `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` set to `False` in your settings?

Comment: Morgen! _ROBOTSTXT_OBEY_ is set to true_. Does is not correct? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It should be `False` as according to your log your spider stops because it's obeying website.com/robots.txt file. Just set it to False :)

Comment: It has advanced! Thank you very much Granitosaurus! Now I´m not obtaining results but I think that due to the xpath I´m obtaining null values. Granitosaurus I´ve seen a post from you where you talk about call something at Chrome to see the HTML content, could you help me to obtain the correct xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Use scrapy_rotaing-proxies to get away:

> pip install [scrapy-rotating-proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies)